# Why does this program change the list with no return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    myFunc(a)
    print(a)

def myFunc(myList):
    myList[1] = 100
```

Im studying for my final for my first compsci class about python. This code came up and I dont understand why the value of the list changes when the myFunc() doesnt have a return value. Why doesn't it just print out 1,2,3? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @dawg That is not what is happening here.

Comment: @Lattyware: ur right... Still a duplicate however.

Comment: thank you guys sorry about duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are mutable.  Python functions pass arguments by assignment. When you call `main` it creates a list and associates it with the local (to `main`) name `a`. It then calls `myFunc`, which assigns *this same list* as the value of the local (to `myFunc`) name `myList`, which mutates it.  (I.e., no copy of the list is made; `myFunc` is working with the *same* mutable object.)  Control then flows back to `main`, which prints the (now changed) value of `a`.

Comment: thank you so much i understand now!!!!!!! its like an epiphany. SOrry for asking stupid questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently taking an intro class to Python too so I'll just try my best to answer this question.

Simply put, not all functions need to return a value.

In your function, MyFunc, you effectively changed the list without having to return a value. You just took an extra step to make your program more organized. It would be the same if you just had the contents of your function inside the main function.